# Python _ Automatic screenshot taker_with transcript

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, video

I would like to wirte a small program, which automatically takes a screenshot of a video, when a certain amount of pixel (say 100 ) "pixel_change" change.

I also have a subRib file, which holds the transcript of the video file. I would like to kind of make a image book, where I have the images of the slide, and on the bottom the transcript for the appropriate slides.

1. Automatically extract all slides from videos with timestamb.
2. Read subRib file
   [image]
3. Assign the slides according to their timestambs to each text block from the subRib file
4. Export Textblock and accosciated slides as one image

[image]

How can I do it ?

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Could you provide what research you've done, what code you've thus-far completed and if neither former or latter are proficiently available- I would suggest to post less ambiguous questions that detail errors and hiccups you've encountered instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try openCV probably will be good module to achieve your goal. If you want help then i would love to help you out with the code. :)

[Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiRlbWK7vLWAhVINI8KHe6uDr8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.opencv.org%2F3.0-beta%2Fdoc%2Fpy_tutorials%2Fpy_tutorials.html&usg=AOvVaw0VqY2jnj-HYLNJPxY5uLVl) is the link for more info

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be great if you could help me. I am new to opencv, but it looks awesome. I have everything installed. right now, I am trying to get a list of all the timestamps of the frames. ... but I am struggeling.

Comment: What I tryied:import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True

while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  time = vidcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
  print('Read a new frame: ', success)
  print('Time:' + str(time))
  # cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  # count += 1

Comment: The code looks promising, i would suggest you now to look for all the corners and centers pixels like 50 pixels of each corners and match the colors from last frame, i guess thats all you need. Right ? If i am missing something then please correct me. :)

Comment: Thanks  a lot ! I updated my question, so that you can better understand my final goal. Right now I am at step one. How would you look at all corners and Center pixles ?

Comment: And for the timestamp: I get the error: name 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC' is not defined

Comment: Can you help me ?